Self hosted WCF service in a managed app with a certificate reporting and error "HTTP request forbidden with client authentication scheme Anonymous"
I have a Windows service that self hosts a WCF service for clients to connect to, current it using unsecure HTTP connection. I have bought an SSL certificate from a trusted CA that I already use to secure my web application successfully.
I want to secure the Windows service so that the host server and clients can install the certificate and only these clients would be authenticated to connect to the WCF service.
As a test I have created a simple Host/Client console application to test the security using the certificate.
Currently the service is showing as secure when I navigate to the baseline address, but when the client attempts to connect to the service and use one the calls, I get an error in the client application stating "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."
Right now I have the client set up to present the certificate to the WCF service defined in its app.config, so it shouldn't be trying to connect anonymously. I've tried changing the authentication settings in ISS, but obviously that wouldn't work as the WCF is not hosted in IIS, but as a Windows service and in this test, it is just a console application.
I have the certificate installed on both the server and client "Local Computer - Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and "Local Computer - Personal" stores. I have even tried putting it in the "Trusted People" store.
Below you can see the C# code and the app.configs for the Host/Client.
Host Program.cs (I have changed the actual URL to testendpoint for security reasons):
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace SimplifiedHostService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISimplifiedHostServiceContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SimplifiedHostServiceMethod(string input);
    }

    public class SimplifiedHostService : ISimplifiedHostServiceContract
    {
        public string SimplifiedHostServiceMethod(string input)
        {
            return "You said: " + input;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("https://testendpoint:8000/SimplifiedHostService");

            // Create a ServiceHost instance
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimplifiedHostService), baseAddress))
            {
                try
                {
                    host.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    host.Close();
                }
                catch (CommunicationException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ex.Message);
                    host.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Host app.config:
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="SimplifiedHostService.SimplifiedHostService">
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="secureBinding"
                          contract="SimplifiedHostService.ISimplifiedHostServiceContract" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="secureBinding">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                            storeName="Root"
                                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                                            findValue="TestCertificateSubjectName" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Client Program.cs
// Shared service contract interface (copied from server project)
using System.ServiceModel;
using System;
 
namespace SimplifiedHostService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISimplifiedHostServiceContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SimplifiedHostServiceMethod(string input);
    }
}
 
namespace WCFClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a channel to the service using the shared service contract interface
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<SimplifiedHostService.ISimplifiedHostServiceContract>("SimplifiedHostService");
 
            SimplifiedHostService.ISimplifiedHostServiceContract channel = null;
            try
            {
                // Create a channel to the service
                channel = factory.CreateChannel();
                // Call the service method
                string result = channel.SimplifiedHostServiceMethod("Hello from client");
 
                // Display the result
                Console.WriteLine("Result from service: " + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the channel factory and the channel
                if (channel != null && channel is ICommunicationObject)
                {
                    ((ICommunicationObject)channel).Close();
                }
 
                factory.Close();
            }
 
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

Client app.config:
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint name="SimplifiedHostService"
             address="https://testendpoint:8000/SimplifiedHostService"
             binding="basicHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="secureBinding"
         behaviorConfiguration="test"
             contract="SimplifiedHostService.ISimplifiedHostServiceContract" />
        </client>
        <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureBinding">
             <security mode="Transport">
             <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                 </security>
        </binding>
         </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="test">
             <clientCredentials>
            <!-- Specify the client certificate -->
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                               storeName="Root"
                               findValue="TestCertificateSubjectName"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
     </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>


Just sharing the experience - in a same scenario, self hosted WCF in a windows service, we had so much problems with setting up SSL that we switched to message-level security. Messages are passed over HTTP but are encrypted and signed internally.

HI @WiktorZychla thanks for the information, my aim to encrypt/secure the transport or the message, as long as it cannot be intercepted and read. switching to message-level security, other than changing the security mode, would there be any other fundamental changes to the code I posted?
If I can get it working in this test application I can attempt it in the main solution.

Just try switch to wsHttpBinding which does encryption by default.

Hi @WiktorZychla Thanks, by switching to wsHttpBinding, I was able to get message level security to work.
By switching from basicHttpBinding to wsHttpBinding will there be any drawbacks in terms of interoperability as I need Windows and Android devices to be able to communicate with the WCF service?
Each would have a the certificate installed.

Not sure if Android has libraries that do ws security out of the box. Do you own research.

I tested it and it does cause problems when using Basichttpbinding.  In fact, it is only necessary to introduce a certificate on both the client and the server to complete the communication. As for the direct difference between the two bindings, this documentation should help you.
